# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Forbidden

Tags: docker, proxy, windows-10

i am new to docker ,installed docker for windows 10 : **version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825**

i tried to execute the first docker pull command but it doesn't succeed , i am beside a corporate proxy and the connection to docker server is working fine .
here is what i got :

`PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Forbidden`.

when i call the link https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ on the browser i get:

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}

edit :

after changing the proxy address i had :

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required

i have followed the same as [windows docker behind a corporate proxy](https://medium.com/@rodrigoriccitellivieira/struggling-with-docker-on-linux-behind-a-corporate-proxy-d98da8e1738d):  ,but still i facing the same issue.

Comment: it's a corporate proxy problem which cause this error.

Comment: How can we solve it?

Comment: you can use cntlm authentication proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i solved the issue by following this step , 
it may work or not depending on you corporate proxy.

find bellow the steps i followed :

1. install the cntlm from : cntlm.sourceforge.net
2. connect to your corporate web proxy using this command :

   cntlm -H -u username -d domainname .

**username** :your domain/proxy account name

**domainname**:  the actual domain name

3. finally you can execute : docker pull

Comment: Can you please narrate exactly what steps (and commands) you followed to resolve the issue?  This helps others.

Answer (score 2):

The normal solution to this is just `docker logout`, that's solved it every time anybody I know has it it. Somehow docker gets its credentials out of order or something.